# What are the tower reload times in Kingdom Rush Frontiers?

Tags: kingdom-rush

In the game Kingdom Rush Frontiers, the tower reload times are only described in words, e.g. "Average", "Fast", "Slow".
What do these correspond to in real times, e.g. 2 s, 1 s?

Answer (score 2):

Ok to answer the question here are the times i found

Slow- 3 Seconds

Average- 1.5 Seconds

Fast- 1 Seconds

Hope this helped you out

Answer (score 1):

You can see the exact shots per second at [Kingdom Rush Wiki](https://kingdomrushtd.fandom.com/). You would simply have to compare the ingame description (f.e. fast) with the stat in the Wiki.

Here are a couple of examples:

- Artilery Tower Level 4 - DWAARP: Attack Rate 3s
- Archer Tower Level 3 - Sharpshooter Tower: Attack Rate 0.5s

To see a convenient listing of every tower visit [KR Wiki - Category Towers](https://kingdomrushtd.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Towers).